# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down

Tags: java, http, connection, shutdown, apache-commons-httpclient

The application throws below errors and then fails to connect to the API. The application and webservers have to be restarted to make the application function again and it is really frustrating.

```
cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(100);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
```

Using CloseableHttpClient and CloseableHttpResponse for handling request and response.

The CloseableHttpResponse is closed in finally section.

```
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1294: Shutdown connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec- Connection discarded
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager- Connection released: [id: 1294][route: {s}->https://xxx.xx.com:443][total kept alive: 10; route allocated: 11 of 50; total allocated: 11 of 100]
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager- Connection manager is shutting down
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1303: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1301: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1300: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1281: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1258: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1296: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1302: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1278: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1291: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-1298: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection- http-outgoing-596: Close connection
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager- Connection manager shut down
["http-bio-8080"-exec-296] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire- http-outgoing-596 << "[read] I/O error: Socket closed"
["http-bio-8080"-exec-1832] ERROR com.xx.xxxxxxx.xxx.util.HttpClientHelper- Error while invoking web service
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: It is a java application

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this error? I have come across the same issue, DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection -- Shutdown connection, Any solution?

Comment: We had used PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and setting maxtotal and defaultmaxperroute values as per out requirement and it fixed the issue.